# Imprimir documento de liquidação

Tags: vb.net

Boa tarde,

Tenho os seguintes dados :

```
Filial As String, Serie As String, Tipodoc As String, NumDoc As Long
```

E queria imprimir o documento via .net, a questão é que é um documento de liquidação e não existe o `BSO.Comercial.Liquidacoes.ImprimeDocumento` como existe para vendas e compras.

Como posso imprimir usando algo semelhante?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A unica forma de imprimir o documento é fazendo a inicialização da impressão tal como no caso dos documentos de venda. Ou seja utilizando a API de impressão de documentos `Plataforma.Mapas.ImprimeListagem()`. Antes disso é necessário fazer a inicialização do contexto do mapa, tipicamente são os *dados da empresa* e *Selection Formula* que vai restringuir os dados e que neste caso é a chave natural do documento, neste caso *TipoDoc, Serie, NumDoc*.

No Git tem um exemplo [documento de venda](https://github.com/PrimaverabssDeveloper/ERP10Extensibility/blob/master/Custom%20Events/Primavera.Logistics.Extensibility/Static/GlobalFunctions.cs).

Comment: Pois, optei por essa solução visto que não ha um ImprimeDocumento() para este tipo de docs.

Comment: Bom dia. Talvez isto ajude:
Dim dt As ITesBS100.ITesBS
dt = New ITesBS100.ITesBS
dt.Documentos.ImprimeDocumento(...)